# Solaris GREP command use

Tags: solaris

I want to search specific word in extension files, tried below command but things are not working

I want search words like `project25`, `project22`, `project30`  in a middle of line

command line:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | grep '\(project\dd\?*\)\'
```

Please help me on this command in SOLARIS

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what output you are looking for. For instance, if you want to find the names of files which contain the string 'project22' you could try something like:

find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -lw 'project[0-9][0-9]' +

A bit more clarity on exactly what you are trying to achieve would help...

Comment: Yes right i am searching string 'project22' but the command you provided is not working in SOLARIS and i am getting 
find: incomplete statement

Comment: Sorry, missed the {} - 

find . -name '*.txt' -exec grep -lw 'project[0-9][0-9]' {} +